# push object to an array within multiple loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of objects like this `[ { category: 'xxx' }, { author: '12345' } ]`. My task is search this array and find in mongoDB to return _id `[ { category: '_id' }, { author: '_id' } ]`

I have code to do this, I create an empty array `arrSearch` and when it found the _id, it will push to this array. But after running, the array is empty, no data pushed. I'm not sure what wrong with it.

```
export const getObjIdFromCondition = async (conditionArr) => {
    var arrSearch = []

    try {
        await conditionArr.map(obj => {
            for (let key in obj) {
                switch (key) {
                    case 'category':
                        const foundCategory = Category.findOne({ slug: obj[key] }).orFail()
                        foundCategory.then(resp => arrSearch.push({category: resp._id})) // push obj to array
                        break
                    case 'author':
                        const foundAuthor = Author.findOne({ author_id: obj[key] }).orFail()
                        foundAuthor.then(resp => arrSearch.push({ author: resp._id }))
                        break
                    default:
                        break
                }
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('arrSearch', arrSearch) // -> empty array
}
```

Can you help me? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Your database query needs to be synchronous as well otherwise the `map` function will be returned without waiting to get the data and your arrSearch will log without data

Answer (score 0):

I try to use promise all and it works.

```
export const getObjIdFromCondition = async (conditionArr) => {
    try {
        var arrSearch = await Promise.all(
            conditionArr.map(async (obj) => {
                for (let key in obj) {
                    switch (key) {
                        case 'category':
                            const foundCategory = await Category.findOne({ slug: obj[key] })
                            return { category: foundCategory._id }
                        case 'author':
                            const foundAuthor = await Author.findOne({ author_id: obj[key] })
                            return { author: foundAuthor._id }
                        default:
                            break
                    }
                }
            })
        )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    console.log("arrSearch", arrSearch)
}
```